# input onchange function calling not only on change

Tags: javascript, jquery

So as the title states I have dynamic form that adds inputs dynamically and one of those inputs dropdown on change calls for val(this) function and I would also like to call this function when somebody adds this field so when a.AddSpell on click function is executed

```
$('div#ChampionInput').on('click', 'a.AddSpell',function(){
    var championName = $(this).closest(".Champion").find(".ChampionInput").val();
    if($.inArray(championName, championsWithExtraSpells)==-1){
                OptionsChampion = '\
                   <option value="Passive">Passive</option>\
                   <option value="Q" selected>Q</option>\
                   <option value="W">W</option>\
                   <option value="E">E</option>\
                   <option value="R">R</option>'
                   ;}
            else{
                OptionsChampion = '\
                    <option value="Passive">Passive</option>\
                    <option value="Q" selected>Q</option>\
                    <option value="Q2">Q2</option>\
                    <option value="W">W</option>\
                    <option value="W2">W2</option>\
                    <option value="E">E</option>\
                    <option value="E2">E2</option>\
                    <option value="R">R</option>\
                    <option value="R2">R2</option>';}
    $(this).siblings('.SpellChanges').append(
    '<div class="Spell" data-id="'+$(this).siblings("div.SpellChanges").children("div.Spell").length+'">\
        <select name="change['+$(this).parent('div').data('id')+'][]" onchange="val(this)">\
           '+OptionsChampion+'\
        </select>\
        <input type="text" name="championSpell['+$(this).parent('div').data('id')+'][]" readonly>\
        <br>\
        <div class="Change">\
        <textarea type="text" size="20" rows="3" cols="50" maxlength="500" name="SpellDescription['+$(this).parent('div').data('id')+'][][]" placeholder="Enter Description" required></textarea>\
            <select name="SpellChange['+$(this).parent('.Champion').data('id')+'][][]">\
               <option value="buff">Buff</option>\
               <option value="nerf">Nerf</option>\
               <option value="new">New</option>\
               <option value="change">Change</option>\
               <option value="bugfix">Bugfix</option>\
            </select>\
            <a href="#" class="AddChange" onclick="return false;">Add Change </a>\
            <a href="#" class="RemoveSpell" onclick="return false;">Remove Spell</a>\
        </div>\
    </div>\
    ');
    //alert($(this).siblings('div.SpellChanges').children('div.Spell').last().children('input').html());
});
```

alert($(this).siblings('div.SpellChanges').children('div.Spell').last().children('input')); this is what I've tried to target that field but I have no idea how to call on change with (this) in it.

Here is also html

```
<div id="wrap">

<form name="second_form" id="second_form" action="#" method="POST">         
    <select id="season" name="season" onchange="checkseason();">
        <option value="newseasons" selected>Season 3+</option>
        <option value="oldseasons">Season 1, 2</option>
    </select>
    <input id="patch" type="text" name="patch" placeholder="e.g. 4.20" required autofocus><br/>
    <a href="#" id="AddChampion" onclick="return false;">Add Champion</a>
        <div id="ChampionInput">
        </div>
        <br><br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit">
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Perhaps jQuery `.trigger()` is what you need? [Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/).

Comment: First of all I have a problem with targeting that select. Ive even added to this select id = test  and tried that alert($(this).siblings('.SpellChanges').children('#test').attr('name')); and i still get undefined

Comment: `.children()` only returns direct descendants (one level). It looks like the `select` is inside a `div`, and therefore not a direct descendant. Use `.find()` instead - it searches all the way to the bottom of the DOM.